# How to bind the IP address of Centos in vmware?

Tags: centos, ip

Now the IP will change if I reboot,how to configure it so that the IP won't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the system-config-network command in console.
Uncheck Edit Devices->ethX->Use DHCP, and set the static IP of the server.